# This pointer in inheritance

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, this

Ok,here the think if I use **this** pointer in a derived class then will I be able to access the base class's member functions and data members with it?if yes then it should also be able to access the private members of the base class or am I wrong?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: 2nd. definitively wrong. except friend...

Answer (score 2):

> if I use this pointer in a derived class then will I be able to access the base class's member functions and data members with it?

You'll be able to access the base class protected or public member functions and data members even without using `this->`.

```
class Base {
protected:
    int x;
public:
    void nothing() {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void something() {
        this->x;           // equivalent to `x`
        this->nothing();   // equivalent to `nothing()`
    }
};
```

---

> If yes then it should also be able to access the private members of the base class or am I wrong?

You are wrong. Private members are accessible only within the class/struct that declares them or `friend` classes/structs and functions.

```
class Base {
private:
    int x;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void something() {
        this->x;   // nope!
    }
};
```

Comment: Note: Removing `this` might have an effect when the base class it a template (although you can use `TheBase<T>::theMember` instead of `this->theMember`.

Comment: @juanchopanza `TheBase<T>::theMember` would have the effect of preventing virtual despatch also though if its a function.

Comment: That's not strictly true.  Access is by name, _not_ by what is named, and it's perfectly possible to access private members through a pointer to member, for example.  It's using the name in a context where it resolves to something which is private that is the error, not accessing the entity.

Answer (score 0):

A derived class "contains" all of the members of the base class,
and the compiler will generate whatever code is necessary for
the access to work.

Access control is orthogonal.  Physically, nothing changes; the
private members are still visible, and the compiler could also
generate the code necessary for the access.  Access control
affects names, not the referenced entities; if, after the
compiler does name lookup, the name resolves to a private
declaration, the compiler will generate an error.  (On the other
hand, you can still access the entity through means which don't
require the name; e.g. if you have a pointer to member which
designates it.)